# My sd card that was 16 gb its now only 236 mb

Tags: sd-card, retropie

I used a 16 gb sd card to installl retropie in my raspberry pi 3, but now my computer says its just a 240 mb card. How do I format it to the original state?

Comment: Your computer is probably only seeing the boot partition.

Comment: I presume you are using Windows - this is just the size of the boot partition. The Card is almost certainly OK and will run on a Pi.

Answer (score 2):

When you write an RPi OS image to a SD-Card, it actually creates two partitions. The first one (`/boot`) has a 256MB size and because of the filesystem which is `FAT32`, is accessible for your Windows box. The second one (`root`) has whole other size of the SD-card and formatted as `EXT4` filesystem and because of that you can't see there.
It's the output of `fdisk -l` (8GB SD-Card):

```
Device         Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        8192   532479   524288  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      532480 15466495 14934016  7.1G 83 Linux
```

---

To fix it, you should use a tool like "SD Card Formatter". Check [this link](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/03/how-to-format-pi-sd-cards-using-sd-formatter/) out for more information.